# Jogo da Velha Dúvida

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
        void selecionarBloco() {
        
            while (blocoSelecionadoCorretamente == false) {
                   System.out.print("Qual casa você irá marcar (" + jogador +"):");
                   int blocoSelecionado = teclado.nextInt();
            
                   if (blocos[blocoSelecionado].equals("X") || blocos[blocoSelecionado].equals("O")) {
                        System.out.println("BLOCO JÁ SELECIONADO!");
                        blocoSelecionadoCorretamente = false;
                   } else {
                        blocoSelecionadoCorretamente = true;
                        blocos[blocoSelecionado] = jogador;             
                   }
              }
        }
```

Quanto coloco ele para funcionar o jogo da um bug muito estranho fazendo 9 jogadas automaticamente e dando empate. Gostaria de saber o que tem de errado.

Método: Enquanto o blocoSelecionadoCorretamente for falso, ele irá fazer os seguintes comandos, pedirá uma casa para o usuário, e colocará dentro de blocoSelecionado, após isso ele fará a os teste para ver se a casa selecionada já esta ocupada, se sim ele retorna blocoSelecionadoCorretamente = false, se não blocoSelecionadoCorretamente = true, acabando o método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua pergunta, você esta omitido aonde você criou a variável `blocoSelecionadoCorretamente`, creio que seja fora da função `selecionarBloco()`

Caso seja o caso, uma vez que `blocoSelecionadoCorretamente` esteja `true`, todas as proximas vezes que `selecionarBloco()` for chamado ele ira passar diretamente do while, criar ela na primeira linha da sua função pode funcionar

```
boolean blocoSelecionadoCorretamente = false;
```

Porem, recomendo tentar de outra forma:

Envez de criar uma variabel do tipo booleano, você pode usar [break](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp) para sair instantenamente de um loop, ficaria assim:

```
void selecionarBloco() {
    
        //Deixa o loop infinitamente até que break seja chamado
        while (true) {
               System.out.print("Qual casa você irá marcar (" + jogador +"):");
               int blocoSelecionado = teclado.nextInt();
        
               if (blocos[blocoSelecionado].equals("X") || blocos[blocoSelecionado].equals("O")) {
                    System.out.println("BLOCO JÁ SELECIONADO!");
               } else {
                    blocos[blocoSelecionado] = jogador;             
                    break;
               }
          }
    }
```